AWS CLI version 2.22.0 unable to use device authentication
When trying to use the --use-device-code option for setting up the CLI sso configuration, I am still prompted with an OIDC/PKCE URL.  I am unable to authenticate the session on a different device.  Has anyone gotten this to work?
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-cli-adds-pkce-based-authorization-for-sso/
Update.  I can't post this as a comment because "It's too long".  :-|
So, it appears to work if you don't give it a session name.
aws configure sso --profile dev --use-device-code
SSO session name (Recommended):
WARNING: Configuring using legacy format (e.g. without an SSO session).
Consider re-running "configure sso" command and providing a session name.
SSO start URL [None]: https://www.example.com/start
SSO region [None]: us-east-1
Attempting to automatically open the SSO authorization page in your default browser.
If the browser does not open or you wish to use a different device to authorize this request, open the following URL:
https://device.sso.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
Then enter the code:

They fixed it in version 2.22.2.
I'm surprised no one on here experienced that issue, yet again, most people don't use the latest CLI versions.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/aws-cli/v2/CHANGELOG.rst
